# Scrapy error on Scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Here is what I trying to do.  I want to scrape emails from a number of websites. I have a file using which I can input the scrapy all the list of url. This is how I tried to extract email:

```
import scrapy
import datetime
import re
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from techfinder.items import EmailItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class DetectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"

    start_urls = ["http://example.com"]#[url.strip() for url in starturlfile.readlines()]


    def parse(self, response):

        DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = 
        {
            'scrapy_proxy_rotator.ProxyMiddleware': 1,
        }

        PROXY_ROTATOR = 
        {
            'username': 'user1',
            'password': 'pass1',
            'proxies_file': 'proxies.txt',
        }
        emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', response.body)        
        emailitems = []
        for email in zip(emails):
            emailitem = EmailItem()
            emailitem["email"] = emails
            emailitem["source"] = response.url

        return emailitems
```

I ran the command as:

```
scrapy runspider scrapyDemo.py -o t.json -t json
```

And got the error:

```
2017-02-09 12:58:34 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-02-09 12:58:34 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'FEED_URI': 't.json'}
Usage
=====
  scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>

runspider: error: Unable to load 'scrapyDemo.py': No module named techfinder.items
```

Why I am getting this error? Also how I can crawl the complete website and get the emails in an optimized way using my program? I am using proxy rota tor for multiple proxy support. If possible how I can add user-agent definition in my code?
Kindly help me with this problem.
Please let me tell you I am not scraping emails for spam. As I have many of the website I trying to acquire the emails from it.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `run spider` command you need to use not a filename but a `Spider` name, which is set as an attribute in class:

```
class DetectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    ....
```

So:

```
$ scrapy runspider test  -o t.json -t json
```

Comment: Please can you tell me what is the meaning of this error. I try to use the way you specify: `Usage
=====
  scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>

runspider: error: File not found: test
`  Can you please read my question and let me know your suggestion. I will be glad to hear :)

Comment: Looks like your scrapy installation is invalid. Try to list all spiders:  `scrapy list`. Also there should be file `scrapy.cfg` with sections `[settings]` - where to look for settings, and `[deploy]` - where all files are located.

Comment: Spiders should be located in `<project-dir>/spiders` folder relative to installation root.

Comment: Show output of `scrapy list` and `cat scrapy.cfg`.

Comment: `scrapy list`: `Scrapy 1.3.0 - no active project

Unknown command: list

Use "scrapy" to see available commands
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135242/discussion-between-jaffer-wilson-and-eugene-lisitsky).